# Facebook login window close when screen rotates

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented facebook into my application.

Login process is working properly. When I click on facebook image then it opens facebook login window.

[image]

But When I rotate the emulator then it Close the login window.

[image]

Any solution.

Comment: when screen rotated activity is destroyed and recreated

Comment: Show us some code. Sounds like its not recreated after rotation

Comment: yeah its recreating activity but how to prevent it.

Comment: you can prevent activity from recreating but you should handle configuration change. Check the docs there is a topic related to the same. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in manifest file for your Activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

Comment: Note : When you declare your activity to handle a configuration change, you are responsible for resetting any elements for which you provide alternatives. If you declare your activity to handle the orientation change and have images that should change between landscape and portrait, you must re-assign each resource to each element during onConfigurationChanged().

Comment: screenSize is not there

Answer (score 2):

The approach I took was to not allow the OS to restart your activity after the layout configuration change. To accomplish this, add this line within activities that you want to prevent from restarting in your manifest file:

```
<activity
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
 ...
 >
```

Optionally, you can handle the configuration change in code in case there are some layout changes you want to make manually, such as reloading a new view from XML. This is done by overwriting the onConfigurationChanged() method in your Activity class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    //Handle config changes here, paying attention to
    //the newConfig.orientation value
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: what kind of code I need to write in between Any small ex. ?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: @Raghunandan  I understand the concept that u talking about. but facebook login window is using webview.. when it rotates webview is destroyed . how to restore this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be because of screen orientation configuration change, you can try one of following solutions:

1. As some of the answers suggested, you could distinguish the cases of
   your activity being created for the first time and being restored
   from savedInstanceState. This is done by overriding
   `onSaveInstanceState` and checking the parameter of onCreate.
2. You could lock the activity in one orientation by adding
   `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` (or "landscape") to 
   in your manifest.
3. You could tell the system that you meant to handle screen changes
   for yourself by specifying `android:configChanges="screenOrientation"`
   in the  tag. This way the activity will not be recreated,
   but will receive a callback instead (which you can ignore as it's
   not useful for you).