# Multi Fragment Save/Restore fail after Rotate device

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem, in my Activity I have a NavigationDrawer, I use to call 3 fragment.
I have implemented the onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState for the Fragment active, all the data are saved correctly, but when I rotate the device, the savedInstanceState (inside onCreate) is not null and the NavigationDrawer not call the Fragment.

now I have broken my head to think a solution....

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dualpane);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
            instantiateFragments(null);//init
        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (null != toolbar) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            //set the back arrow in the toolbar
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        //Create the AccountHeader
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();

        Fragment_1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Fragment 1")
                .withIdentifier(1);
        Fragment_2 = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Fragment 2")
                .withIdentifier(2);
        Fragment_3 = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                .withName("Fragment 3")
                .withIdentifier(3);

        builder = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
                .addDrawerItems(
                        Fragment_1,
                        Fragment_2,
                        Fragment_3
                ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
                    //              .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
//                             @Override
//                             public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
//                                 // do something with the clicked item :D
//                                 if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
//                                     String name = ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName().getText(CustomListActivity.this);
//                                     getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
//                                     FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//                                     FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//                                     Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: savedInstanceState = " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "NULL" : "Not NULL"));
//                                     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//                                         switch (position) {
//                                             case 1:
//                                                 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment1.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG1).commit();
//                                                 break;
//                                             case 2:
//                                                 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG2).commit();
//                                                 break;
//                                             case 3:
//                                                 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment3.newInstance("Terzo"), FRAGMENT_TAG3).commit();
//                                                 break;
//                                         }
//                                     }else{
//                                         instantiateFragments(savedInstanceState);
//                                     }
//                  /*                 FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//                                     Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
//                                     fragment1 = (Fragment1) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG1);
//                                     fragment2 = (Fragment2) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG2);
//                                     fragment3 = (Fragment3) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG3);
//                                     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//
//                                         // List<Fragment> lista = mFragmentManager.getFragments();
//                                         if (fragment == null) {
//                                             mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment3.newInstance("Terzo"), FRAGMENT_TAG3).commit();
//                                             mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG2).commit();
//                                             mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment1.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG1).commit();
//
//                                         } else {
//                                             //mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
//                                             mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commit();
//
//                                             switch (position) {
//                                                 case 1:
//                                                     mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment1).commit();
//                                                     break;
//                                                 case 2:
//                                                     mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment2).commit();
//                                                     break;
//                                                 case 3:
//                                                     //bSavePage = new Bundle();
//                                                     //bSavePage.putString("section_name", "Quarto");
//                                                     //fragment3.setArguments(bSavePage);
//                                                     Bundle args = new Bundle();
//                                                     args.putString("someString", "Quarto");
//                                                      // Put any other arguments
//                                                     fragment3.setArguments(args);
//                                                     Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), Fragment3.class.getName(), args);
//                                                     mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment3).commit();
//                                                     break;
//                                             }
//                                         }
//                                     } else {
//                                         // probabilmente e' accaduta una rotazione
//                                         mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commit();
//                                         switch (position) {
//                                             case 1:
//                                                 mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment1).commit();
//                                                 break;
//                                             case 2:
//                                                 mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment2).commit();
//                                                 break;
//                                             case 3:
//                                                 Bundle args = new Bundle();
//                                                 args.putString("someString", "Quarto");
//                                                 // Put any other arguments
//                                                 fragment3.setArguments(args);
//                                                 Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), Fragment3.class.getName(), args);
//                                                 mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment3).commit();
//                                                 break;
//                                         }
//                                     }*/
//                                     getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
//                             }
//                             return false;
//                         }
//                     }
//
//              )
                .withOnDrawerListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                                              KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(CustomListActivity.this);
                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

                                          }
                                      }

                )
                .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState);

        result = builder.build();





@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        //add the values which need to be saved from the accountHeader to the bundle
        outState = headerResult.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mMyFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        mFragmentManager.putFragment(outState, "SaveFrag", mMyFragment);
        outState.putString("TAG", mMyFragment.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
        instantiateFragments(inState);
    }

    private void instantiateFragments(Bundle inState) {
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (inState != null) {
            mMyFragment = (Fragment) mFragmentManager.getFragment(inState, "SaveFrag");
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMyFragment, inState.getString("TAG"));
        } /*else {
            // inizializzazione
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment1.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG1);
            transaction.commit();
        }*/
    }
```

EDIT**
I have implemented onPostCreate in my Activity and moved the code withOnDrawerItemClickListener inside and now works!

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostCreate");

        builder.withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                    String name = ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName().getText(CustomListActivity.this);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
                    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: savedInstanceState = " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "NULL" : "Not NULL"));
                    //if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        switch (position) {
                            case 1:
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment1.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG1).commit();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG2).commit();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment3.newInstance("Terzo"), FRAGMENT_TAG3).commit();
                                break;
                        }
                    //}else{
                        //instantiateFragments(savedInstanceState);
                    //}

                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is my question. overthere I lost fb login window. but when I try the given answer the fb webview not creating again. in your case fragments. you can just try the solution. May be it should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170384/facebook-login-window-close-when-screen-rotates

Comment: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"` Just try this

Comment: I've tried, but nothing, same problem